# How to connect a mac and Android device via WiFi-direct?

Tags: network, wifi, android

I've got a M1 Pro 16" MBP and an Android 11 device between which I want a WiFi-direct connection.

The Android device supports WiFi-direct and can connect to another WiFi-direct-capable Android device just fine. I am able to communicate between them as expected.

macOS obviously supports WiFi-direct as it is the basis for AirDrop transfers but I am unable to find a way to join a WiFi-direct network from a mac.

To avoid the XY problem:
I'm an Android dev and want to use ADB wirelessly. I currently have to do this indirectly via a WiFi access point where speeds obviously vary greatly and 100Mbit/s is the max speed you can realistically get (often lower). WiFi-direct should allow for much more stable speeds at up to 250Mb/s (maybe even higher). (High speeds are important here as deploying a ~60MB binary is in the critical path of the feedback cycle.)
My current plan is to have a WiFi-direct connection between the MBP and Android device such that I can use ADB over IP over it instead of an indirect WiFi connection.
A WiFi hotspot from the phone is not an option as I also need to download large things often enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an Apple representative, AirDrop does not actually use WiFi-direct but a custom protocol: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/12885?answerId=694254022#694254022

Apple implementing WiFi-direct is therefore technologically unnecessary from their perspective and could therefore only possibly happen if Apple was forced to implement open standards such as WiFi-direct by competent regulators.